# Is `grep -P` (Perl/Python regex) portable on most linux distributions

Tags: shell-script, grep, pcregrep

I prefer (Perl/Python Compatible Regular Expressions) regular expressions.

`man grep`:

> ...., but  only  work if pcre is available in the system

Is this supported on the most common linux distributions?

I don't care for freebsd, solarix, busybox, ...

Comment: short answer: yes. (and is 3 times faster then the default)

Comment: Why don't you use `ack`?

Comment: A second endorsement for ack.  ack is written in Perl itself, so you get the full Perl regular expression set, plus you can customize the output using capture groups, as in `ack '#include <(.+)>' --output='$1'`.  (Note: I wrote ack.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PCRE](http://pcre.org) is installed on pretty much all *server* and *desktop* Linux systems, but you can't necessarily expect it on lightweight systems or embedded systems (phones, routers, TVs, and other [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_Things)), as they often have very trimmed versions of the standard userland (basically, anything with a [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/about.html) base is all but guaranteed to lack PCRE).

Debian has a [Popularity Contest](http://popcon.debian.org/) feature that measures installation metrics on various packages.  `grep` (25th most common, 176k installs) depends (*not* optionally) on `libpcre3` (94th most common, 174k installs).  I cannot explain the discrepancy, but I also wouldn't worry about it.

It should be safe to assume that modern desktop and servers running full Linux distributions will have versions of `grep` compiled with PCRE support.

Still, if you want PCRE with a better assurance of portability, don't rely on `grep -P` or `pcregrep` (9363th at 1k installs) or `ack` (21728th at 180 installs), use `perl` (88th at 175k installs) directly:

```
perl -ne 'print if /regexp/'
```

Note, there are servers that intentionally lack perl, python, and php for "security purposes," namely that many rogue scripts (e.g. [rootkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit)) depend on these and therefore cannot run.  This is very rare (and kind of silly since there are plenty of potent rogue POSIX shell scripts).

Note 2: Perl is slow (as is python).  LibPCRE is much faster, but the simpler your regexps, the better performance you'll get.  If possible, use `grep` alone (BRE, basic regexps) or else try `grep -E` (ERE, extended regexps) rather than diving deeper into PCRE land.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that with the push of Docker being bigger and bigger in 2015 it's no longer safe to assume such a thing, Ubuntu is popular (the most popular) for Docker but Alpine Linux (a busybox based distro) is becoming popular.

Comment: [Alpine's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) notes it "is primarily designed for x86 routers, firewalls, VPNs, VoIP and servers," so I wouldn't call it a desktop distro. That said, I did include servers ... but [DistroWatch's popularity rankings](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity) do not rank [Alpine](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=alpine) in its top 50 distros, so I stand by my statement.

Comment: Do you have popularity metrics of Linux distros hat run Docker (which would make it more of an appliance than a general server)?  Or did you mean that run *within* Docker?  I can't find either, nor any other evidence to back your claim. Even if such a ranking does exist, Alpine won't be in the top five, and as the only distro lacking grep+libpcre, it would be a corner case. There are exceptions to every rule.

Comment: @AdamKatz 6 years later it's about the 30th on the list :P

Comment: @jinawee – All I see is improvement. [By install count](https://popcon.debian.org/by_inst "WARNING: this is a 18MB text file"), `grep` is currently 21st (206.0k installs) and `libpcre3` is 45th (205.9k installs). `grep` has one more install than `gzip` and `login` (which are tied) and one fewer install than `bsdutils` and `lsb-base` (also tied).

Comment: Eight years later, @JordonBedwell is proven right. After Docker themselves pushed for Alpine Linux in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11000827, it apparently is widely used. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729118/, neither `ack` nor `perl` are included in the Alpine base image. A lot of workflows depending on `grep -P` need special attention.

Comment: **Please note that this question expressly excludes busybox and that Alpine is based on busybox.** Alpine is indeed very common for minimalist servers; Does its base image even ship with GNU coreutils? That package didn't even exist in Alpine until 2021, when they also added PCRE; I wouldn't be surprised if `grep -P` actually works in Alpine now (as long as you install both). That said, I do not suggest using `grep -P` on anything that needs to be portable beyond desktop distros (including those adapted to servers).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, I've seen `pcre` on a lot of Linux distributions such as CentOS, Ubuntu, RedHat, Debian and other distribution based on these. and I think it won't make you any problems. also the source is available:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcre/files/pcre/